# Crystal Reports. How do I check if a string is alphabetically earlier than another string?

Tags: crystal-reports

This sounds stupidly easy, however I've been googling for over an hour and I have found nothing.

I tried < and >, but they don't appear to be working. Perhaps it is another part of my code, but I can't even confirm < and > work as I suspect, because there is no documentation that states what these operators do with strings.

So, how do I compare strings in CR? >?

Comment: Just tried in CR2008, and the comparison operators work as expected with alphanumeric strings. Special characters might behave funny, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ryan said, the `<` and `>` work as expected with alphanumeric strings. I believe they're case-insensitive.

To debug your specific problem, I suggest adding a detail section, dropping in the formula field containing the expression you want to test, as well as the component variables. Then you can look at the values, and find out where you're going wrong.

For example, add fields for:

- @City1LessThanCity2
- Table.City1
- Table.City2

Comment: Thank you. I solved my issue by doing operations while printing rather than reading. None the less this answers my original question perfectly. [Thanks Ryan for the original comment =)]